# Certain fonts not working with @font-face?

Tags: html, css, font-face

Here's what's frustrating here.  I got a font pack for Sansation, and then tried to use it with @font-face.  The regular version works and the "bold" version doesn't.  I checked the filename and it's definitely correct.  My understanding was that any font should work.  Am I missing something?

```
@font-face
    {
        font-family: sansation_regular;
        src: url('/fonts/sansation_regular-webfont.ttf'),
            url('/fonts/sansation_regular-webfont.eot');
    }
```

I then, without changing the font-family in the CSS corresponding to the text element, change it to:

```
@font-face
    {
        font-family: sansation_regular;
        src: url('/fonts/sansation_bold-webfont.ttf'),
            url('/fonts/sansation_bold-webfont.eot');
    }
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably also run the font through FontSquirel to get the full set
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

the css it'll generate will be something like:

```
/* fonts */
@font-face {
font-family: 'sansation_regular-webfont';
src: url('../fonts/sansation_regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/sansation_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/sansation_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/sansation_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../fonts/sansation_regular-webfont.svg#sansation_regular-webfont') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'sansation_bold-webfont';
src: url('../fonts/sansation_bold-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/sansation_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/sansation_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/sansation_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../fonts/sansation_bold-webfont.svg#sansation_bold-webfont') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Also I'd avoid using full ULR refs - just check the path to your fonts folder is correct from the css file

Comment: Oh, yeah, I actually already planned on that, I was just doing it this way for the purposes of the example.  I was using relatives then switched to absolute and the absolute magically worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the Sansation with @font-face, and both the regular and bold versions seem to work when installed as system fonts. Maybe double check the paths?

Comment: Interestingly enough, switching it to an absolute path worked.  Thanks for your time, though!

Answer (score 0):

If using a local file directory isn't working, try an absolute path.  The following solution worked:

```
@font-face
    {
        font-family: sansation_regular;
        src: url('http://www.siteAddress.com/fonts/sansation_bold-webfont.ttf'),
            url('http://www.siteAddress.com/fonts/sansation_bold-webfont.eot');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @DOLOisSOLO and @Mr. Lavalamp suggested, absolute paths should work.

For future reference, is your CSS file in a folder? If so then a relative path URL can be used, for example:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: sansation_regular;
    src: url('../fonts/sansation_regular-webfont.ttf'),
        url('../fonts/sansation_regular-webfont.eot');
}
```

The dots representing one level up each time.